# How many equations of motion? The higher order derivatives are highly correlated

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, computational-physics, differential-equations, complex-systems

**Note: the bounty text above states "second order linear differential equations". It is an empirical observation that this is the case for the particular system I'm studying, please read "n-th order linear differential equation" instead**

I have an object that moves in space, and I am trying to represent its movement in terms of differential equations.
This is the trajectory of the object:

[image]

This is a real-world object, whose position is sampled every thirty seconds. It moves slowly and accelerates slowly, so we will assume that the sampling rate is sufficiently fine-grained. Please just assume it: **I can model the system computationally, later**, and the $\Delta t$ can thus become arbitrarily small.

**I want to learn a set of differential equations** of the form $\frac{d^{n}x}{dt^{n}}$ for $n$ which varies between 1 and whatever it is the highest order derivative that adds information to this system.

**Question**: What is this $n$?

**Here is my approach to answering this question:**

These derivatives are computed by <s>finite differences</s> [smoothed finite difference](https://pysindy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pysindy.html?highlight=SmoothedFiniteDifference#pysindy.SmoothedFiniteDifference) with a window frame of 5, and they look highly correlated with one another starting from order 3-4. The finite differences were discarded upon suggestion by @AndersSandberg , and now it appears that each derivative is correlated with its associated second order derivative:

[image]

This is the correlation matrix between each derivative and the next

[image]

I have around 90 objects that are following the same physics, and they all show similar pattern between the position and its time derivatives: from the pair $(\frac{d^1 x}{dt^1},\frac{d^3 x}{dt^3})$ onward, **each additional derivative can be expressed as a linear function of the corresponding acceleration** (twice-differentiation, $\frac{d^n x}{dt^n} = c_0 \frac{d^{n+2} x}{dt^{n+2}} + c_1$).

**Is it correct to claim that, in this system, the equations of motion are these three**:

$\begin{align*}
x(t) = c_{1,1} \times f_1(t) + 0 \times g_1 (x) + c_{1,3} \times h_1(\frac{dx}{dt}) + c_{1,4} \times i_1(\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^2})\\
\frac{dx}{dt}(t) = c_{2,1} \times f_2(t) + c_{2,2} \times g_2(x) + 0 \times h_2(\frac{dx}{dt}) + c_{2,4} \times i_2(\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^2})\\
\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}(t) = c_{3,1} \times f_3(t)  + c_{3,2} \times g_3(x) + c_{3,3} \times h_3(\frac{dx}{dt}) + 0 \times i_3(\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^2})\\
\end{align*}$

The zero coefficients are for ease of read, the various $c$'s are some constants.

For each of the two coordinates of course. Please let me know if something is not clear, and thanks in advance!

Comment: You have another issue: measurement noise growth. Approximating the derivative with a finite difference gives an error of order $|f''(\zeta)|\Delta t/2$ where $\zeta$ is a point in the time interval from t to $t+\Delta t$. Note that noise can drive pretty big instantanteous accelerations or higher order derivatives of what you are measuring, that then become big error terms in your approximation. So you should not trust the values you see for higher order derivatives at all! They are likely artefacts of noise growth rather than real.

Comment: This is correct. At a later stage I can increase the sampling rate to any frequency (say, 0.001 ms, the speed is in [0,4] m/s) so the noise will be less problematic. I can also replace the forward finite differences with the total-variation regularized derivative as recommended by [1]. Do you think the result would change significantly? In any case, if the time derivatives (measured let's say with a radar and an accelerometer) are correlated with one another, is this a good evidence for the number of equations that describe the system?
[1] https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.1517384113

Comment: Thank you @AndersSandberg, I have computed the derivatives via smoothed differences now which should be more resilient to noise. The picture changed slightly, now each derivative is a linear function of its second-order time derivative. I modified the question accordingly

Comment: Two questions: (1) Why do you think that there are derivatives beyond the second at play here? (2) Why do you believe that you can accurately use $\Delta t\approx30\,\mathrm{sec}$ to be $\mathrm{d}t$?

Comment: Thank you @KyleKanos for the comment. 
(1) The motion of this object is not treated by traditional kinematic approaches so we cannot assume that there are any conserved quantities (e.g. momentum or angular momentum). I tried fitting polynomials and trigonometric functions and combinations thereof on the velocity as a function of position, and acceleration as a function of position and velocity, and it does not work. The (unknown) equations of motion correctly describe the motion of this system (which is not random) if they correspond to empirical measurements, short of errors

Comment: (2) I don't believe it really, but this is what I have. The problem in this question concerns primarily the theoretical consideration that there are three degrees of freedom per coordinate (6 in total) in this system, and whether the presence of a strong enough correlation between higher order derivatives and lower order derivatives is a good evidence for that. My reasoning is that, because I can always express $\frac{d^{n+k} x} {dt^{n+k}}$ as a linear function of $c_0 \frac{d^{n} x} {dt^{n}} + c_1$, then I am not free to choose $\frac{d^{n+k} x} {dt^{n+k}}$ if I have measured the lower orders

Comment: To be a bit more clear about my question 1: presumably there is some underlying phenomena that you are trying to explain. Typically, one would derive an equation of motion utilizing mathematics, rather than curve-fitting techniques. I would expect that your equations need to come first, then add in the tracking to match those equations.

Comment: Of course, if this is a stochastic process, as the trajectory suggests to me, then higher order terms are largely useless and you need to focus on accounting for the [Wiener increments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process).

Comment: Also, in regards to (2), the finite difference approach assumes that the step is small enough such that $\left(f(t+\Delta t)-f(t)\right)/\Delta t$ reasonably approximates the derivative $\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}t$. Point (2) was to point out that I (strongly) suspect that $\Delta t\simeq30$ sec is far too large and that the finite difference approximation you are using is invalid.

Comment: Concerning (1): I am studying the motion in space of a biological organism, which does not necessarily satisfy the properties of physical systems (e.g. conservation of energy/momentum). The motion is non stochastic, in the sense that there is a destination that the object is trying to reach every time they move (speed > 0), and their trajectory is aimed at that particular point given some constraints from the world (e.g. mountains). Curve-fitting is needed because the rules according to which this object moves are unknown, and learning them is the objective of this study.

Comment: Concerning (2): I should have mentioned it in the post. Once I have some equations of motion (obtained by curve fitting, as discussed earlier) I will build a computer simulation of this object's motion. In light of that, I know I can make $\delta t$ arbitrarily small at a later stage, provided that the basic argument proposed in this analysis makes sense (i.e., that jerk and the other higher order derivatives don't matter). In the new iteration, the finite differences were replaced with smoothed finite differences, they should be more resilient to noise. Thanks @KyleKanos for the feedback :)

Comment: There is absolutely no explanatory power of fitting data to a curve, unless you have a formal mathematical theorem to back it up. Do you have a physical reason as to why a biological organism would move according higher order derivatives?

Comment: The objective is in fact to exclude that this is the case, and to prove instead that six degrees of freedom are sufficient. I understand that the traditional method to approach EoM modeling in kinematic is to begin with considerations about energy or conserved quantities, and then apply one of the three formalisms and derive the EoM mathematically; however, for systems that do not have any such conserved quantities, and yet behave regularly, there must be a way to go from data to theory and not the other way around.

Comment: But this is the overarching theme, and does not strictly relate to the problem at hand. The question I have now is simply: if the additional time-derivative after the position are linearly correlated with some of the lower order, this means that they can be expressed as (second) order linear differential equations x'' + ax + b = 0. There exist solutions to this system (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=x%27%27%27%27+%2B+ax%27%27+%2Bb+%3D+0+ ). Does this suffice, to state that x(t), x', and x'' are enough to describe the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plots indicate that higher order derivatives aren't providing any real additional information — and you probably cannot trust the 3rd and higher ones too much either, given the low granularity of your original data, regardless of the smoothing procedures used.
So it would be a mistake to focus on the relations between those curves or to try to infer too much from them.

As already suggested by Kyle Kanos in the comments, this motion definitely looks stochastic. You answered that, since your object is being attracted to a target, your system isn't stochastic, but notice that a system with both a deterministic and a stochastic terms (like virtually any real-world system, where noise is unavoidable) is called stochastic. This means that you'll probably be looking for a differential equation such as [Langevin's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation), which includes a fluctuating random term, to model your object's motion.

As for the question of how many dimensions your system must have, you could try approaches such as [time-delayed embedding](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2018.01679/full) or, if you insist in using the higher order derivatives, check how many can be dropped by applying [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction) methods.

Comment: Low granularity aside, I find it hard to imagine many processes involving [snaps, crackles or pops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth,_fifth,_and_sixth_derivatives_of_position) that might be applicable here. Stochastic processes are almost surely the way to go, but I suspect that OP (and their collaborator(s), if any), are unfamiliar with that field (given their response to my remarks about it).

Comment: @KyleKanos I also find it very unlikely. It might very well be something more complicated then Langevin is needed, but I wouldn't expect $x'''^{+}$ to be part of it.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at the Langevin's approach for modeling noise, and it could be an improvement over the current model to add a stochastic term for noise.
In another iteration of this study I have applied [Kalman filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) to denoise the trajectories (the $x(t)$), which is a standard techniques for reducing Gaussian distributed noise used in geospatial analysis. 
Does it make sense to think that, if the $x(t)$ have been denoised, then the $x(t)$ row should not contain the noise term and all other rows with equations should?

Comment: @DaneelR. If the noise satisfies the assumptions (random, with constant, low amplitude, etc.) then it might work, but only if the underlying (deterministic) system is simple enough. Besides, if the sampling rate is not increased, the jaggedness of $x$ is likely to dominate its derivatives.

Comment: BTW, @DaneelR. those long stretches of approximately linear movement interspersed by some local 'explorations' reminded me of [Lévy flights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight). You might want to take a look at this walk and its variations.

Comment: Thank you @stafusa, I had a look at the literature on Lévy flights and it seems indeed that the prevalent opinion in the community is that something interesting happens when an organism transitions from random walk/brownian motion to a Lévy flight. It seems that, for the next update to this work of mine, it makes sense to iterate over all subtrajectories and find those that satisfy brownian motion, and those that satisfy Lévy flights, and those that are explainable by pure inertia. Thanks again for the help!